# PrimeNG: Datatable UI building list

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to build this UI where it uses the schoolName as the title and creates a new header for each schoolName and uses it as the heading for careOferingName.

[image]

HTML dataTable :

```
 <p-dataTable [value]="this.careOfferingSpaceList" [editable]="true" >
              <!-- <p-header><div class="ui-helper-clearfix" style="width:100%"><span class="results-text" >Showing {{mccCacheService.numOfSystemAlerts}} results</span> <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-plus" style="float:right" (click)="showDialogToAdd()" label="Add System Alerts"></button></div></p-header> -->         
              <p-column field="id" hidden="true"></p-column>
              <p-column field="careOfferingName" header="Total Spaces" ></p-column>         
              <p-column field="spaceAvailable" header="Spaces Available" [editable]="true" ></p-column>         
            </p-dataTable>
```

CareOfferingSpace class :

```
 export class CareOfferingSpace {
        public id: number;
        public careOptionId: number;
        public weekNo: string;
        public startDate: string;
        public endDate: string;
        public spaceAvailable: string;
        public careOfferingSpaceAvailableId: number;
        public schoolId: number;
        public schoolName: string;
        public careOfferingName: string;
      }
```

Sample object response :

```
"careOffering": [
         {
            "id": 3,
            "careOptionId": 1713,
            "schoolId": 422,
            "schoolName": "ABC Learning",
            "careOfferingName": "Before School",
            "spaceAvailable": null,
            "careOfferingSpaceAvailableId": 3
          }, {
            "id": 3,
            "careOptionId": 1713,
            "schoolId": 422,
            "schoolName": "ABC Learning",
            "careOfferingName": "After School",
            "spaceAvailable": null,
            "careOfferingSpaceAvailableId": 3
         }, ...
```

Comment: What do you need? What is the question?

Comment: Proper way to build that UI table I posted above

Comment: `*ngFor` on `<td>` would be totally acceptable